# change css class after an if else statement of PHP query

Tags: php, mysql, css

The program refreshes the values of `$pat_no` every 5 seconds, what i want to know is, how can i change the css class property of the div being refreshed after the query is made. after comparing the values, the class will change accordingly(like changing the background color) if the value is changed in the database so that the changed value is easily noticed and reverts back to its old class after 5 seconds too.

Here's the code

```
<?php
include 'connect.inc.php';
$query = "SELECT patno, compare, cubeno FROM tblcube WHERE cubeid = '1'";

if($query_run = mysql_query($query)){   
    while($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)){
        $com = $row['compare'];
        $pat_no = $row['patno'];
        $cube_no = $row['cubeno'];

        if($com == $pat_no){
            //change css class of <th>
            echo "<th>".$pat_no."</th>";
        }
        else if ($com != $pat_no){
            //change css class of <th>
            echo"<th>".$pat_no."</th>";
            $query2 = "UPDATE tblcube set compare = '$pat_no'where cubeid = '1'";   

            if($query_run= mysql_query($query2)){

            }
        }

    }
}
```

?>

Here is the JS code

```
function AJAX(){
try{
xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
return xmlHttp;
}
catch (e){
try{
xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); // Internet Explorer
return xmlHttp;
}
catch (e){
try{
xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
return xmlHttp;
}
catch (e){
alert("Your browser does not support AJAX.");
return false;
}
}
}
}
```

also, here is the portion of index.php

```
<head><script src="ajax1.js"></script>
<script type = "text/Javascript">
refreshdiv_c1v();</script>
<body>
                        //cubicle1
                        $query = "SELECT patno, cubeno FROM tblcube where cubeid = '1'";
                        if($query_run = mysql_query($query)){   
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)){
                            $pat_no = $row['patno'];    
                            $cube_no = $row['cubeno'];  

                     echo " <tr class = 'rows' id = 'cub1'>
                            <th class = 'name'>".$cube_no."</th>
                            <th class = 'num'><div id = 'c1v'>".$pat_no."</div></th>    
                            </tr>";
                        }}
                        </body>
```

Comment: Is your 5 second update being done by js?

Comment: no, I tried that too. because there is an html code where in the above cell has its own class declared previously(maybe that's why the class i declare here doesn't work), and it calls ajax and this php file to refresh every 5 seconds.

Comment: @TecBrat yes it is. should i add it also in this page?

Comment: Yes you should definitely add the js as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is it would go something like this in your php file...

```
 if($com==$pat_no){
     return json_encode(array("msg"=>true,"data"=>$pat_no));
 } else {
     $query2 = "UPDATE tblcube set compare = '$pat_no'where cubeid = '1'";   
     if($query_run= mysql_query($query2)){
          return json_encode(array("msg"=>false,"data"=>$pat_no));
     }
 }
```

And something like this in your jquery...

```
 function checkPat(){

 $.getJSON('yoururl.php',function(data){

    if(data.msg==true){
    // Update your class here
    $('.theTRthatchanged').addClass('yourClass');
    //Remove after 5 seconds
    setTimeout(function(){
    $('.theTRthatchanged').removeClass('yourClass');},5000);     

    } else if(data.msg==false){
       //Do nothing I guess.
    }

 });

 }

    //Set the checker to fire every 2 seconds or whatever interval seems best.
   setInterval(checkPat,2000);
```

Not quite exactly like this, but this is the main idea of how it would work.  How you would go about selecting the tr that changed is up to you, and might be a bit tricky.  You'll have to maybe attach data-id attributes or something of the sort, and send that back with the json.
  But you get the idea.

Comment: I'll try this first. I really find it hard posting the JS code. even after using the Ctrl + K. Only the first line gets in the code. sorry, maybe try editing the post later. anyway thnks. will give my feed back in a few minutes